# Is it possible to add a custom CSS at angular-cli.json by link?

Tags: css, json, angular

I would like to add some custom CSS on my angular-cli.json file, but I can't find a solution about it. I tried to use something like that:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "http://site.test/mycss.css"
  ],
```

But it's not working. Someone can say if there is a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use sass instead of pure css

```
"styles": [
   "styles.scss"
]
```

in the style.scss, use the @import from sass and let the sass handle it

```
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

Note: I think you can use an 'http' address